# How can I only load up the terminal via grub then upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, grub2

So after the upgrade I made last night I can't load up the GUI properly. I have a feeling the upgrade died half way through.

Grub is working. All the kernals are listed.

That being said how can I:

A) Make grub load into terminal only. No gui.
B) How can I reinstall gnome?
C) How can I try to install the upgrade for ubuntu again? It may or may not let me "do-release-upgrade". So what are my options here?

Thanks!

Comment: does control-alt-f1 work? Is so log in there and on the commandline issue the command :)

Comment: I just mashed ctrl-alt-f1 everyone i could mash it and it didn't see to have any effect ha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hold the Shift key before the OS starts to boot to get to the grub menu. Then select the boot to recovery mode option. This will lead to a selection screen that will let you select Root Prompt.

Comment: oh recovery mode for some reason. it keeps booting up the GUI which doesn't work. I just need to modify stuff in grub commands by pressing "e". I tried "quiet splash text" but that didn't work or perhaps i just did it incorrectly.

Comment: Recovery mode should not proceed to the GUI unless you select "Resume normal startup", or something like that. If you select "Root prompt", it should put you into a text-only system console.

Answer (score 0):

At the start, press shift to enter the grub menu. Then press e to edit  the grub commands. For the argument linux in the grub remove "quiet splash" and replace it with "text".
For example:

linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3 ..... root=UUID=d1f1 .... ro quiet splash $vt_handoff

Should be edited to:

linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3 ..... root=UUID=d1f1 .... ro text $vt_handoff